# multiple toggle button automatically turn off

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, togglebutton

I developed multiple toggle button with this code.
but I want to add function of automatically turn off

For instance,
First, click "a" button to turn on, then click other button to occur automatically turn off the "a" button.

```
 const [Selected, setSelected] = useState({
        "a": false,
        "b": false,
        "c": false,
        "d": false,
        "e": false,
    });
```

```
const select = (e) => {
        
            setSelected({
                ...Selected,
                [e.target.value]: !Selected[e.target.value],
            });
        
    }
```

```
<button onClick={select} className={selected["a"] ? "style selected" : "style"} value="a">a</button>

<button onClick={select} className={selected["b"] ? "style selected" : "style"} value="b">b</button>

<button onClick={select} className={selected["c"] ? "style selected" : "style"} value="c">c</button>

...
```

It can be possible with this code?
plz let me know what should I code for that, and plz suggest how to approach or something better ways

Comment: Do you want only one button to be on?

Comment: What I understood from your question is you want to enable one button at a time and other buttons to be turned off right?

Comment: @MDMNauman yes sir

Comment: @DreamBold For now, I'm hoping for that

Answer (score 3):

In JS `undefined` is a falsy value. So `selected["a"] ? "style selected" : "style"` would be evaluated the same way if `selected["a"]` is `false` or `undefined.

So your initial state can actually be an empty object, and to turn all other buttons off when clicking a button, create a new empty state with only that button turned on.

```js
const { useState } = React

const Demo = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});
      
  const select = (e) => {
    setSelected(() => ({
      [e.target.value]: !selected[e.target.value]
    }))
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={select} className={selected["a"] ? "style selected" : "style"} value="a">a</button>

      <button onClick={select} className={selected["b"] ? "style selected" : "style"} value="b">b</button>

      <button onClick={select} className={selected["c"] ? "style selected" : "style"} value="c">c</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />)
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That's what I would do as well, beat me to it :) I did learn from your answer how to make a react code snippet for future answers so thanks for that.

Comment: "undefined is a falsy value" didn't know that!!! Thank you for letting me know

Comment: Your question is not clear. You'll need to give me more details.

Comment: Oh! Your answer already do that I asked!! Thank you~

Comment: Can I ask you something? you said "undefined is a falsey value". so If I want to turn off all buttons, create a new empty state like "setState({})" It means all of state are false(turn off) right? Then, how to handle the opposite situation effectively? LIke all of state want to be true.

Comment: Yep. `undefined` in this expression `undefined ? "style selected" : "style"`` would have the same result as `false ? "style selected" : "style"`.

Comment: I add somthing! Plz read it! THX

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
const select = (e) => {
    const prev_selected={...Selected};
    for(let key in prev_selected){
       prev_selected[key]= key===e.target.value;
    }
    setSelected(prev_selected);    
}
```